# Ajax data callback is treated as literal

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, jquery-ui

Ajax data is treated as literal

I'm using jQuery UI AutoComplete. It works fine with local dadta source.But when I change the data source to remote ajax data source, it's not working like the local data source. It seems like it treats the callback data as literal or string not
a datasource like array or JSON, even though the callback data is JSON. Also, the callback data has the same formate as the local data.

Local data source:

```
var local = [
    {
        "label": "item 1",
        "value": "item 1",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "label": "item 2",
        "value": "item 2",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "label": "item 3",
        "value": "item 1",
        "id": 3
    }
];
```

Callback data source that was printed onto the console:

```
[
    {
        "label": "CIS104",
        "value": "CIS104",
        "id": "35"
    },
    {
        "label": "CIS214",
        "value": "CIS214",
        "id": "60"
    },
    {
        "label": "CIS256",
        "value": "CIS256",
        "id": "61"
    },
    {
        "label": "CIS335",
        "value": "CIS335",
        "id": "62"
    }
];
```

This my HTML:

```
<head> 
<title>AutoComplete TextBox with jQuery</title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var localsource = [
  { "label": "item 1", "value": "item 1", "id": 1 },
  { "label": "item 2", "value": "item 2", "id": 2 },
  { "label": "item 3", "value": "item 1", "id": 3}];

  $(function() {
      $("[id$=txtAuto]").autocomplete(
     {
         source: function(request, response) {
             $.ajax(
             {
                 url: "/playground/service/PlayGroundWebService.asmx/GetListOfCourse",
                 data: "{ 'param': '" + request.term + "' }",
                 dataType: "json",
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 async: true,
                 success: function(data) {
                //data.d because it's .NET web application    

                   var remotesource = data.d;
                //It works if remotesource = localsource
                   response(remotesource);
                   console.log(remotesource);
                 },
                 error: function(result) { }
             });
         },
         select: function(event, ui) {
             alert(ui.item.id);
         }
     });
  });      

    </script>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="demo">
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="txtAuto">Enter Course # or title: </label>
            <input id="txtAuto" type="text"  style="width: 600px" />
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell what is the problem? Thanks

**Update 1:**

console.log(data) gives this:

```
Object { d=

"[ { "label": "CIS104", "value": "CIS104", "id": "35" }, 
{ "label": "CIS214", "value": "CIS214", "id": "60" }, 
{ "label": "CIS256", "value": "CIS256", "id": "61" }, 
{ "label": "CIS335", "value": "CIS335", "id": "62" } ]"

}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show you? (Without the `.d` property.)

Comment: I added the console.log(data) in the update 1 above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to use JavaScript eval method to convert remote data source to an JavaScript object (string -> object)

```
// Change var remotesource = data.d; to this:

var remotesource = eval("(" + data.d + ")");
```

Comment: Don't use `eval()`, use `JSON.parse()`. (Or jQuery's `$.parseJSON()`.) Though I think it would be better to fix the server-side code to just return the JSON you need in the first place rather than burying it as a string in the `d` property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what the result is from requesting target the URL?

Run your script in Chrome, and look at the network tab in the console. You should see a request logged when you run the process that fires the ajax call. Click on the request and look at the response, is it as expected? -does it fail?

That's where you need to start.

Comment: Ajax call back is working. The AutoComplete works but it treats the call back data differently, for example If I type "C" it shows C,I,S,1,0,4,.. like that instead of showing CIS104,CIS256